# how to build iOS app with Cloud Build CI/CD

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have iOS application I want build and create ipa file and upload this ipa file to GCP bucket.
Is it possible in GCP Cloud Build?

I am working on GCP cloudbuild cicd pipeline. and using docker build tool ekreative/xcode-build-tools.

My CloudBuild.yaml:

steps:

name: 'docker.io/ekreative/xcode-build-tools:latest'

args: ['create-ipa', '--app', 'helloworld']

Issue I am facing: /bin/sh: 1: xcrun: not found

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Build requires Docker, which is based on a Linux VM.

You probably cannot do it because the only way to run OSX or iOS in the Cloud is to have it backed by Apple hardware as macOS and iOS are not licensed to run on VM's or non-Apple hardware.

Comment: Docker is the option where we can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

If you can build the **IPA** on **linux** or with **docker** you can build it with the cloud build.

Cloud build supports the linux and docker as base images so you can use any of as per requirement and start building the app.

Looks like there is already request, you can check about it more here : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149469695?pli=1

Comment: Can you provide any doc, how to create ipa with docker

Comment: never got chance to test this but this was hanging around my bookmark bar hopefully maybe you can try and dirty your hand and share some insights. https://github.com/jkingyens/docker4xcode

Comment: I am working with  github.com/jkingyens/docker4xcode, Can you help me to create cloudbuild.yaml file. how to write script for this buildtool

Comment: first test locally if it's working with the docker will check on the cloudbuild or i will share the file.

Comment: I am facing issue: Error: Cannot find module '/workspace/build'

Comment: Kindly share the cloudbuild.yaml it would be helpful for me

Comment: is it working first locally thn i can share some cloudbuild plus you are requesting for cloudbvuild file without sharing any context, i am totally unaware what you are trying, where is you Dockerfile, application code, gcr repo, project id.

Comment: Above you share error but where you getting it, what you have done no details. How someone know current status. requesting you to update and share few details so can guide or suggest. else feel free to update the new question with details.

Comment: Sorry but my local docker desktop is not working. any other way so that  can check.

Comment: I am able to run -h, -V, in https://hub.docker.com/r/ekreative/xcode-build-tools but when I try args: ['create-ipa', '--app', 'helloworld'] it showing me error /bin/sh: 1: xcrun: not found